# Where to put Django permissions logic?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-authentication, django-permissions

I have a 'View' which is mostly contain a 'Form', I need one User-Group with edit-permission to see it and edit form, And another User-Group with just view-permission to only can view information, And they can't edit information.

What is the best way to achieve this behavior?

I'm aware of '[permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)' decorator and '[PermissionRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin)' mixin but they are effect on entire view which is not my goal.

I guess I should use [user.has_perm()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) but I'm not sure where to put the logic, in views or forms or somewhere else...

Comment: Why not use a DetailView for the read-only users?  Users w/ edit permission can have a link to the EditView.

Comment: You mean I should create separate detail view? To be honest the 'View' I mentioned is big with fat forms and it use ajax too, I don't want to duplicate that. You are right maybe I can create some simplified view to just display information.
But I wonder what is best practice for this kind of situation.

Comment: Another option might be to hide/show the submit button, and in the backend add a manual check in the form clean() method.

Comment: how about using a Mixin to hold the bulk of the code, and then use very small GenericViews to enable permissions?

Comment: Both of your suggestions will do the job, I will try them and see which one is the cleanest. Thank you